# Trouble using Botan with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, botan

I am using Qt and I am trying to use Botan. Everything seemed to go well, but when I go:

`Botan::BigInt myInt;`

In my constructor it works fine, but on the other hand if I go:

`Botan::AutoSeeded_RNG rng;`

It throws undefined errors:

```
C:\Users\Stevie\Desktop\asfsdf-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-_MinGW__Qt_SDK__Debug\debug\mainwindow.o:-1: In function `AutoSeeded_RNG':
C:\Users\Stevie\Desktop\asfsdf-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-_MinGW__Qt_SDK__Debug\..\..\..\..\botan\include\botan\auto_rng.h:40: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan23Global_State_Management12global_stateEv'
C:\Users\Stevie\Desktop\asfsdf-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_1_for_Desktop_-_MinGW__Qt_SDK__Debug\..\..\..\..\botan\include\botan\auto_rng.h:40: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan13Library_State10global_rngEv'
:-1: error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have no idea why it would work with a BigInt but not the AutoSeeded_RNG, but here are my exact steps:

1. Compiled the Botan source included in the Qt Creator source at "src/libs/3rdparty/botan/"
2. I installed Botan using the Windows Installer (1.10) from [their website](http://botan.randombit.net/download.html#current-stable-series-1-10).
3. I took the libBotan.a, libBotand.a, botan.dll, and Botand.dll and put them in the location where I installed Botan (C:\botan). I overwrote any of those files that already existed.
4. I then created a new Qt project, and inside of the .pro file I added the following lines:

   > INCLUDEPATH += "C:/botan/include"
   >   LIBS += "C:/botan/libBotan.a"
5. Next, I go into my "mainwindow.cpp", and add:

   `#include <botan/botan.h>`

   **Everything compiles up to here successfully.**
6. I now add this to my constructor:

   `Botan::AutoSeeded_RNG rng;`

Now the above errors are thrown, and cannot be ran. If I replace the "AutoSeeded_RNG" with "BigInt", then it compiles perfectly.

Thanks for any help, Hetelek.

Answer (score 4):

The statement to link against the Botan library looks strange to me. Normally, you specify library directories using the `-L` switch and add a library with the `-l` switch, i.e you should use

```
LIBS += -L"C:\botan" -lBotan
```

Note that the prefix and suffix of the library are not specified in `lbotan`. The linker will automatically look for a `libbotan.a` or `botan.dll`, depending on your environment.

Botan is also part of QtCreator. Maybe you should have a look at [their repository](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator/qt-creator/trees/master/src/libs/3rdparty/botan). You can find `.pri` and `.pro` files there and probably only need to copy them. They also have written a `.qbs` driver for the new Qt build system.

**Edit:** I just compiled Botan from the QtCreator sources, as you also mentioned in your post. I then copied all the generated libraries in my own directory and I also used the `botan.h` which was shipped with QtCreator. On Linux I had to add

```
LIBS += -L"/dir/into/which/i/copied/botan/dlls" -LBotan -ldl
```

to the qmake `.pro` file. Note the additional `-ldl` otherwise I got undefined references to `dlym`, `dlerror` etc. I could compile a simple example with `Botan::AutoSeeded_RNG` without problems.

Comment: Changing how I define my LIBS didn't help unfortunately :(

Comment: When you added `BigInt`, did you also use it? For example, try to add two `BigInt`s Otherwise the compiler might just optimize it away. I'm also curious, if you used the same compiler for Botan and your program.

Comment: Yes, I did actually use it and it was fine.

Comment: Can you try to use Botan together with the header that ships with QtCreator? Might be that you run into problems, when the .cpp is from the Creator but the .h from their website.